# let soft navigation bar (back, home, recent) overlap my layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to let the Android soft buttons (back, home, recent) **overlap my layout** (activity), I think it's normal behavior with reader app or playing video, ... 
For example:
The normal will be looked like this :
[image]
And what I want is :
[image]
(line 2, line 3 is overlapped by the soft buttons).
I do google and see people asked how to avoid it, but now I want it to happen and I don't know how. I already tried with :

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

or

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

but they seem does not work.
Please help me if you know how or any idea.

Comment: try this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

BottomNavigationView is added in support library v25

Comment: Thanks @RahulKumar, but it's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by adding these lines of codes

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_OVERSCAN);
    }
```

Hope it help anyone have same issue.
Thanks.